# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined when trying to navigate a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I want to locate and extract data from a Javascript object.

The object is:

```
let object = { a: 2, b: { c: "x", d: [1, { e: 3 }] } };
```

I want to get the `{e : 3}` object

If I do:

```
object = object['b'];  // Result is { c: "x", d: [1, { e: 3 }] }
object = object['d'];  // Result is [1, { e: 3 }] 
object = object['1'];  // Result is { e : 3 }
```

However if I do

```
let object = { a: 2, b: { c: "x", d: [1, { e: 3 }] } };
const path = 'b.d.1';

for(const pathPart in path.split('.')) {
  object = object[pathPart];
  console.log(`object = ${object}`);
  console.log(`pathPart = ${pathPart}`);
}
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Comment: `console.log(pathPart)` and see what you get.

Comment: I guess you are trying to iterate `path.split('.')`, maybe you should try `for...of`

Comment: This maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yhbc4u3t/

Comment: You also got two lines you didn't show in the question that told you what the error was: `object = undefined` and `pathPart = 0`; you'd get more if you moved the logs *before* the thing that fails, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
for(const pathPart in path.split(‘.’))
```

This puts the indices 0, 1, 2 in `pathPart`, not the array members.

Switch your `in` to an `of` in your for loop.